# Exibição de dados não funciona

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu preciso exibir registros vindos do banco, estou fazendo isso através de um while e inserindo cada campo em uma td, mas se eu não limitar o número de registros no próprio select, eles ficam todos na mesma linha (td). Segue abaixo o código:

```
$select  = "SELECT descricao, nome, datahora_final, valor, tipo_valor FROM teste limit 1";  
$hoje    = date('Y-m-d');
$result  = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);
while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
     echo '<td>' . $exibe['descricao']      . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $exibe['nome']        . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $exibe['datahora_final'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $exibe['valor']          . '</td>';
}     
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Se alguém tiver uma sugestão de como resolver, agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, isso é só uma questão de lógica.

> tente adicionar a tag tr

```
$select  = "SELECT descricao, nome, datahora_final, valor, tipo_valor FROM teste";  
$hoje    = date('Y-m-d');
$result  = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);
while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
     echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>' . $exibe['descricao']      . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $exibe['nome']        . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $exibe['datahora_final'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $exibe['valor']          . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}     
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Realmente era apenas isso, obrigada!

Comment: obrigado, você.